# Why does Groovy's CliBuilder depend on apache commons-cli, which isn't included in groovy-all?

Tags: groovy

So I've been attempting to use the Groovy `CliBuilder`, as described here:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html

However, it depends on classes missing from `groovy-all-2.4.7`, specifically those in Apache's `commons-cli` library.

Ok, so I could add that dependency. But I find there *is* what looks like a version of the Apache `CliBuilder` class bundled in `groovy-all` in the `groovyjarjarcommonscli` package!

Firstly, why bundle that at all?

Secondly, why not use it to back Groovy's CliBuilder implementation?

Thirdly, can I rely `groovyjarjarcommonscli` being there for use in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting Paul King from the Groovy mailing list on 29/3/2018:

> The `groovy-all` jar doesn't bundle Groovy's optional dependencies such
>   as: `ant`, `junit`, `bsf`, `commons-logging`, `log4j`, `jline`, `testng`, `xstream`,
>   `commons-cli`, `jansi`, `ivy`, etc. It includes all of Groovy's modules and
>   embeds a small set of required dependencies for its own internal
>   purposes like `asm` and `antlr` and `commons-cli`.
>
> This lets you write scripts or classes which also use those
>   dependencies directly or indirectly, e.g. Hibernate uses `antlr`, Spring
>   uses `asm` and importantly they might be different versions and that's
>   okay.
>
> The embedded `commons-cli` is used for the command-line tools (`groovy`,
>   `groovyc`, `groovysh`, `groovyConsole` etc.). There are other technical
>   reasons like classloader issues related to the approach we have taken
>   but mostly it's a separation of concerns issue. We might change what
>   CLI handling package we use internally and we might supply different
>   modules which offer different `CliBuilder` implementations which might
>   have different dependencies. We don't want to tie all these things
>   together. Technically, you can use the `groovyjarjarcommonscli` package
>   if you want direct access to the `commons-cli` library though it's not
>   recommended and it's not possible via `CliBuilder` - it is specifically
>   designed not to use the internal one. In the future with JDK9/10+ we
>   will likely not make such embedded packages visible at all.
>
> *Long story short, add the `commons-cli` dependency to your project
>   and/or classpath. That's the correct approach.*